# Manage keyboard events through class in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, events, object, qt4

I'm trying to retrieve a key, and then pass it to the window class...
I stuck to it...
Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "game.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Game g(4);
    MainWindow w;

    w.doSomething();

    while(QString text = keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)->text()){ // this is not working
        g.action(text);
        w.update(g.getState());
    }

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Should I wrap the Game class inside the w class as a private member or something?
I tried... without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[keyPressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent)  is a QWidget member function, so if you need to listen to the key events, you should override it in your subclass.
It looks like, from the code you provided, for you it should be MainWindow.